# Querying Firebird database results in Java Heap Space error

Tags: java, firebird, dbeaver, jaybird

I'm having some trouble with Firebird. Some SQL queries are getting the error "Java Heap Space".

I've revised all queries and seems to be right. But, after doing some tests, I've noted that the error only occurs when SQL query has no limits of returned rows.
If i run the query using `SELECT  FIRST(10) field1, field2 from table`, it returns the result from db, without `FIRST()`, the error occurs.

The original server where Firebird was installed has limited memory, so I just installed Firebird on my personal computer, restored the backup and tested it. My current computer has a lot of ram and CPU to run this simple query and The same problem occurs.

My Firebird version is 2.5. I've searched in Firebird official documentation, but haven't found anything helpful. Anyone knows what could be causing this error?

Below is the print of error and my computer task manager during the tests.

[image: FireBird Java Heap Space Eror]

[[image: TaskManager2]]

Comment: Why are you still using Firebird 2.5.0? The latest 2.5 is 2.5.8. 2.5.8 was released this year, 2.5.0 was released 8 years ago.

Comment: How many rows will your query retrieve without using `first`?

Comment: i'm using 2.5 version to replicate exactly environment that was running on original server. Maybe i should update Firebird to latest version and see if it can solve the problem?

Comment: "How many rows will your query retrieve without using first" 
I don't know. It crashes before return all rows =/  
But i think it should something near 150 ~ 250 rows. (at least was what end user tell me when reported the problem)

Comment: You could always do a `count(*)` to actually know how many, as I wouldn't expect 250 rows to result in such an error (unless this application has really tight memory config, or it has columns with very large blobs). Upgrading you Firebird version has no effect on this (otherwise I'd have included that in my answer). Your Firebird version is just really old with known security bugs. It should have been upgraded years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the memory usage of Firebird server itself. Your query tool is a Java application (it looks like DBeaver, but could also be a different Eclipse-based application), and retrieving all rows consumes too much memory. When Java can not allocate sufficient memory, this results in a `OutOfMemoryError` with message *"Java heap space"*

You either need to configure that application to use more memory, or find out if it can retrieve rows in pages instead of fetching all. Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver) itself will retrieve all rows when the query is executed in auto-commit mode, so maybe you will need to execute it in a transaction.

Alternatively, as you already found out: don't query all rows.

Comment: Yes, i'm using DBeaver to test my SQL queries. 
But, this database is used in old software developed in Delphi and in specific function, the software use this query to retrieve data from DB and seems like it can't retrieve all rows. So, i've just restored the DB to my local machine and tried to run SQL query direct to db, and this error was occurred, and i think it's the same problem which crash the delphi application.

Comment: @WilliamGustavoMarquetti The error is a Java specific error, so you can't have the same problem in Delphi (although of course if way more rows are selected than expected, maybe the Delphi application also runs out of memory).

Comment: I know, and i think this is the problem, like Delphi also runs out of memory.

The SQL Query seems ok to me... I'm thinking in somehow migrate the database to SQL Server express and see if same problem occurs.
But i don't know how to do it and if it really worth it.

Comment: @WilliamGustavoMarquetti Switching database servers won't solve the problem as it is the client application that has the problem. If you transfer the same amount of data from SQL Server to your application, I suspect it will still run out of memory. You need to find the root cause (which is probably: you're selecting too much data).

Comment: @WilliamGustavoMarquetti most probably Delphi app does not try to read ALL the rows into the application memory, as it almost never has sense to do it. So the application allocates the buffer (sliding window) for few dozens or hundreds rows and keeps fetching their from the server as long as previous rows were processed one way or another. // Instead of DBeaver you may try free "Flame Robin" based on IB++ library, or IBExpert based upon FIB+ Delphi library. And see if they would run out of memory too after Fetch All command. I also wonder if your query contains BLOBs

Comment: `retrieve all rows when the query is executed in auto-commit mode` is it really required to be hasty, instead of just let user to scroll to the end and then commit on close? Also, would JayBird auto-fetch BLOB contents even if fields content were not really demanded by a client app? Dunno about DBeaver, but IBExpert would not show BLOB contents in a regular grid, it would do it in a special BLOB Editor window, if requested by user

Comment: @Arioch'The It depends, I may actually have confused an edge-case of Jaybird's behavior with the common behavior. But depending on the exact retrieval used in the application, Jaybird may fetch all rows at once. This is done to avoid certain limitations in Firebird and its implementation and still support certain JDBC features. As always, this is a trade off.

Comment: @Arioch'The

I dind'nt  notice that before, but yes, in this query has tow blob fields.
I've commented these fields and DBeaver could retrieve correct data. 
Well, i think this could be the problem. But, to change this SQL Query, i will need to recompile entire Delphi project again, and i don't know if all necessary files was provided to our company (i'ts a long history...)

Comment: @Arioch'The

Yeah, seems that i've found the problem.
These Blob fields was filled with BMP images, and unnecessary large images. 
After sometime debugging with your little tip, i found it.
In table "EMPRESA" the Blob fields was used to store company logo in high-res (why?!). In that case, the image has 15mb an that was the reason for crashing DBeaver and Delphi application. I just extracted, compacted and reinsert the images and seems to be solved. Thanks! :)

Comment: Storing data in BLOBs has sense - it provides for easier copying (deploy other instances, backups, etc). Some guys even keep the program inside BLOBs so they can easily deploy updates to all client workplaces

Comment: @Arioch'The
Yes, storing files into database has some sense. But, in this specific case, was misused... Since these images are used only as logo in some reports. So, i think the developer should compacted the files before insert it into database. 
Using a file with 15mb as logo for a report seems like a bad idea. And the which the sql query was constructed, it was retrieving these image (with 15mb) for each row... In this case, the query should retrive 98 rows, and for each row, the image, so, it was consuming 1.47gb of memory...

Comment: @WilliamGustavoMarquetti there can be the sense to keep hi-res logos - because the visual template of reports may be changed, or kinds of report (like from table view to the one pretty A4 page per entry). So it could have had sense to start with hi-res ones. Then, of course, the pictures had to be down-scaled accordingly, in the report-creating application ( if bottlenecks of server HDD or client network are not limiting ), or in database caching itself. Alternatively, if never, the app had to downscale on insert. This however is growing from "fix the bug" into "fix the application" realm :-D